# Find most visited Hotel by month in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with couple of customers resided in a hotel for a month or months. I need to find **3 most visited** hotels by month. In case one customer lived in a hotel for three months, then it refers for three month. To be more precise below table `hotel` I have:

| id | usr_id | srch_ci | srch_co | hotel_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-22 | 200 |
| 2 | 12 | 2021-10-11 | 2021-10-22 | 300 |
| 3 | 11 | 2021-10-28 | 2021-11-05 | 200 |
| 4 | 10 | 2021-10-28 | 2021-12-03 | 100 |

Result should look like below:

---

| mnth | hotel_id | rnk | visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10 | 200 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-10 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-10 | 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-11 | 200 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-11 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-12 | 100 | 1 | 1 |

As we can see above, **user_id = 10** stayed in a **hotel = 100** for **3** different months. That means it is counted for 3 different month for a hotel as 1 count. And for `2021-12` month only user = 10 stayed, for this reason in 2021-12 month hotel = 100 is ranked as `1st`.

Comment: Where is your coded attempt at the solution? If none, please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) for a solution, give it an earnest try, and return with a *specific* question regarding attempt such as any errors or undesired results.

Comment: Yes you are right. Before posting a question I made several hours research. But I could not find a way how to group by between two dates. Anyway Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem using `generate_series` function in Postgres. That is what I was looking for. This [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292700/postgresql-split-single-row-into-multiple-rows-based-on-date) helped me. Splitting single row into multiple rows based on date

```
SELECT hotel_id,mnth,visits, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mnth ORDER BY visits DESC) AS rnk FROM (
    SELECT hotel_id,to_char(live_mnth,'YYYY-MM') AS mnth,count(*) AS visits FROM (
        SELECT id,usr_id,hotel_id,date_in,date_out,
        generate_series(date_in, date_out, '1 MONTH')::DATE AS live_mnth
        FROM (
            SELECT *,TO_CHAR(srch_ci, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date AS date_in,
                    TO_CHAR(srch_co, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date AS date_out 
               FROM hotels 
        ) s
    ) s GROUP BY hotel_id,to_char(live_mnth,'YYYY-MM')
) t
```

Comment: Since `srch_ci `is already a *date*  data type You can reduce `to_char(srch_ci, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date` to a much simpler (imho away)  `date_trunc('month', srch_ci)`. The same obviously applies to `srch_co`. See [Date Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html). Note: Once a date column is properly defined/stored there is virtually no reason to convert it to a string except for final *display*.